# How to load all the children of the specific parent?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

There are a lot of related questions in SO, but no one helped me.
I have an entity like this:

```cs
class TaskObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public TaskObject Parent { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TaskObject> Children { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to get all the elements of the specific branch as a list.
For example, I have a tree like this:

```
Task1
    Task2
        Task4
        Task5
    Task3
        Task6
```

The result of my query would be `Task2 Task4 Task5`.
I wrote a function that makes it, but I think there is a better solution:

```cs
private void getSubtree(TaskObject parent, List<TaskObject> items)
{
    items.Add(parent);
    context.Entry(parent).Collection(t => t.Children).Load();
    foreach (var child in parent.Children)
    {
        getSubtree(child, items);
    }
}
```

Is there smth like `context.Entry(parent).GetAllChildren()` in EF Core?

Comment: I you're using SQL as database engine and performance is something that you have to think of, I think it would be better to use something like [SQL Server Recursive CTE](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-recursive-cte/) and [execute it using EF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql).

Comment: @Thibault thanks for the option. I will take advantage of this option if I do not find an ef-like solution.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no any method like that (GetAllChildren()) in EntityFramework.
When you are working with tree, you can cache some paths to improve you searches and navigation.

If you are going to search some nodes then load their path until top of tree:
define a property for tree's node and save all nodes until top of tree. when you move a node you should update that path property too.